# Numbering plan conflict

Tags: asterisk

I am not an asterisk expert, but doing a SIP integration against one.
Now we find an issue and they say they don't have a way to handle it but would like to confirm.

Issue is that we have a numbering plan conflict. Our PBX range goes from 5000 to 8000 numbering range, theirs, go from 5000 to 5199.

So when we call from a conflicting extension, say, 5000 from our PBX dials to 5100 of their PBX, Asterisk returns a SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized message.

Is there any way they could say to their Asterisk to handle them both differently according to the domain calling? I mean, my PBX and phones IP are from another network range, so I guess Asterisk somehow could determine the incoming extension is not from their Asterisk internal numbering plan but an external and should not try to match it against itself...

Am I correct? Is Asterisk that flexible? Option B is someone to change the numbering plan or have a SBC...but...they don't wanna do neither of them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about Context? Contexts are code blocks that calls start from. So you should have contexts such as `internal` for internal calls and `incoming-trunk` for incoming calls. So, when an incoming call comes in it goes to different context and there should be no conflict with internal calls.

Comment: They figured it out with this idea. Seems they did a wrong config with the Contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk compare callerid/username for inbound sip call.

So you can avoid compare by change CALLERID(num) before calling other pbx.

You also should use DUNDI for check if there any sense call that pbx or extension elsewhere.

Anyway, if your developed system is not for home use or TINY load it is REALLY wise idea hire expert.

If you hire expert after do all your staff and notice it not give you acceptable load - that will cost you REALLY alot.

Comment: I am not in charge of the asterisk part, there are "experts" in there side. They miss configured the Context part and worked out. Thanks